# The UIButtonBarItems and UIPopovercontroller references in UISplitViewController delegate methods

Tags: cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller

I could use some clarification regarding where these references come from. As an experiment, I set up a split view controller in my application. When the delegate methods are called, they reference what appears to be a valid UIButtonBarItem and a valid UIPopoverController. I say "apparently" because both of these have non-nil values and resolve to the appropriate class (UIButtonBarItem and UIPopoverController). I did not allocate or initialize either one. Am I supposed to?

I don't see anything in the reference documentation that requires that I initialize these programmatically or says how it should be done. I also don't see where the toolbar that contains the UIButtonBarItem is referred to. I haven't found any examples of tutorials that address this detail more than superficially. If someone can explain or provide a reference to an explanation, that would be helpful.

I am working out how to switch from split view to popover view when going into the portrait orientation. I want simply link an existing button to code that does what the UIButtonBarItem would do. I have a small banner view of my own that serves as a toolbar, and I would rather adapt the button in that to work with the split view controller, if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UISplitViewController` creates both of these for you and you can do with them what you want.  Just add the button that it provides you to your toolbar and store a reference to the popover (so that you can dismiss it, etc.).

Note that when you go back into landscape mode you need to set your popover variable to nil and remove your button since they are no longer valid.

Comment: If that's the case, then I should be able to ignore the UIButtonBarItem and use my own existing button to show and hide popover. I will use the reference to the UIPopoverController, though. If I'm wrong about that, let me know. (I'll give this a try tonight and check your answer once I have confirmed this.)

Comment: Yes, if you want to use a custom button then you can ignore the one that it passes.